# pexpect to automate login to pbrun

Tags: python, automation, pexpect

I am trying to automate pbrun using the following code

```
ssh user@server.com
pbrun -u user1 bash
pass active directory password
run the command
exit
```

I created the following script but it's not able to pass the password for pbrun:

```
import time
import pexpect
child = pexpect.spawn('ssh user@server.com')
child.expect("user@server.com's password:")
child.sendline('Password')
child.expect ('.')
child = pexpect.spawn ('pbrun -u user1 bash')
child.expect ('.*')
time.sleep(10)
child.sendline ('Password') - Active directory password
child.expect ('.*')
child.sendline ('ls')
data = child.readline('ls')
print data
```

The above code successfully does ssh and runs pbrun but is unable to send the password asked by pbrun. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to achieve this by below script, tried python but was not successful, sharing this script which may be helpful to others.

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

if { $argc<1 } {
        send_user "usage: $argv0 <passwdfile> \n"
        exit 1
}
set timeout 20
set passwdfile [ open [lindex $argv 0] ]
catch {spawn -noecho ./myscript.sh}
expect "Password:" {
        while {[gets $passwdfile passwd] >= 0} {
                send "$passwd\r"
                }
}
expect "*]$\ " {send "exit\r"}
close $passwdfile
send "ls\r"
expect eof
```

Run the script as below:

```
./run.exp passfile.txt
```

here passfile.txt has the password in text and myscript.sh has the pbrun command

Answer (score 0):

In general it's not a great idea to *expect* wildcards like `.` or `.*` because those can match a partial input and your script will continue and send its next line potentially **before** the server at the other end is even able to receive/handle it, causing breakage. Be as specific as possible, ideally trying to match the **end** of whatever the server sends right before it waits for input.

You have access to the string buffers containing what pexpect receives before and after the matched pattern in each `child.expect()` statement with the following constructs which you can print/process at will:

```
print child.before
print child.after
```

You might want to get familiar with them - they're your friends during development/debugging, maybe you can even use them in the actual script implementation.

Using sleeps for timing is not great either - most of the time they'll just unnecessarily slow down your script execution and sooner or later things will move at different/unexpected speeds and your script will break. Better expect patterns eventually with a timeout exception are generally preferred instead - I can't think of a case in which sleeps would be just as (or more) reliable.

Check your script's exact communication using these techniques and adjust your patterns accordingly.